# ifft out of memory error in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, out-of-memory

I have wav file and I wanted to filter it (using deconvolution) by taking inverse frequency response and multiplying it to recovered signal in order to get original signal.
The equation is (in frequency domain)

Q=L'*D;

Where the tvalue of L 1x330750 double, and D is 1x512 double
After multiplication Q is 330750x512 double

when I want to get ifft(Q) there is an error
How could I solve this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: in `Q=L'*D`, are you sure the `*` character denote multiplication ? Is it not supposed to be a _convolution_ ? For your `out of memory` error, if it persists, try taking smaller bits of signal at a time.

Comment: My apologies for late reply. Yes, * shows multiplication, since I directly copied it from my Matlab code (where convolution is reached my conv(a,b)). And thank you for your suggestion, the actual problem was with frequency response of the filter, I had to make the length of the frequency response and the signal the same by giving the frequency response certain length.